# Running "compass:dist" (compass) task never ends

Tags: gruntjs, compass, grunt-contrib-compass

I have a grunt configuration which currently have watch and compass modules configured. But when i update any scss file, I am getting message:

*Running "compass:dist" (compass) task*

and nothing happens from that point. Files will not be compiled. It seems like very slow build. I waited for 10 mins and nothing happens. No errors.

**If run with -v -d will get:**
Running "compass" task
[D] Task source: /home/[mypath]/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/tasks/compass.js

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
[D] Task source: /home/[mypath]/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/tasks/compass.js
Verifying property compass.dist exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: force, trace, sassDir="assets/stylesheets", cssDir="../../[path/to/build]"

If I run the "grunt watch" and update any style I will get: *File "assets/stylesheets/style.scss" changed.* but after that will get endless *Running "compass:dist" (compass) task* again.

**Gruntfile.js code:**

```
require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

grunt.initConfig({
    themeDir: "../../[path/to/build]",
    assetsDir: "assets",
    scriptsDir: "<%= assetsDir %>/javascripts",
    stylesDir: "<%= assetsDir %>/stylesheets",

    watch: {
        options: {
            livereload: false
        },

        compass: {
            files: ['<%= stylesDir %>/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass']
        }
    },

    // compass and scss
    compass: {
        dist: { // Target
            options: {
                force: true,
                trace: true,
                sassDir: '<%= stylesDir %>',
                cssDir: '<%= themeDir %>'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
Used versions is:
ruby 1.9.3
compass 1.0.1
node 0.10.33
grunt 0.4.5

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because of the ruby version. After updating to version 2 everything works now.